# NHibernate View in queryover returns duplicate records

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I seem to be having a strange problem with one of my database views that I have mapped with NHibernate. I'm getting duplicate records for one of the views I have mapped. I have the following view objects

```
                      WorkDetailView
                       /          \
                      /            \
                     /              \
                    /                \
          PickWorkDetailView    PutWorkDetailView
```

Each object represents a different view in the database but both `PickWorkDetailView` and `PutWorkDetailView` inherit from `WorkDetailView` because they share many of the same fields.

If I run the following piece of code I get 2 results but if I run the actual database view in SQL Management Studio I get 1 result.

```
List<WorkDetailView> workList = session.QueryOver<WorkDetailView>()
                                       .List<WorkDetailView>().ToList();
```

The interesting part is that when I look at all the items in the `workList` collection above I see one `WorkDetailView` object and one `PickWorkDetailView` object.  Also if I look at the queries NHibernate is running it issues select from all 3 views (WorkDetailView, PickWorkDetailView and PutWorkDetailView).  This does not sound right at all.  I can post xml mappings or my fluent mappings if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NHibernate supports polymorphic queries. So, when you query that base class it will look for all objects derived from that class.

You can control this behavior with the [polymorphism attribute](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class) on the class mapping.

> Implicit polymorphism means that instances of the class will be
>   returned by a query that names any superclass or implemented interface
>   or the class and that instances of any subclass of the class will be
>   returned by a query that names the class itself. Explicit polymorphism
>   means that class instances will be returned only be queries that
>   explicitly name that class and that queries that name the class will
>   return only instances of subclasses mapped inside this `<class>`
>   declaration as a `<subclass>` or `<joined-subclass>`. For most purposes
>   the default, `polymorphism="implicit"`, is appropriate. Explicit
>   polymorphism is useful when two different classes are mapped to the
>   same table (this allows a "lightweight" class that contains a subset
>   of the table columns).

In your example you could set `polymorphism="explicit"` on all 3 mappings.

Comment: Thank you @dotjoe.  This was exactly it.  I'm surprised I missed that one in the NHibernate documentation.  For those of you using Fluent NH you just need to have the following statement in your ClassMap: `Polymorphism.Explicit();`

Comment: Just the answer I needed for my case as well. Much Appreciated.